# Java Performance: regarding using Long.valueOf(..)

Tags: java, performance, casting

We are using **Long.valueOf()** often for same field casting. So that is okay or instead we need to store casted value in other field and then use. 
Example:
we receive particular id in String and where ever we use, we do Long.valueOf(id) every time.

like :

```
void methodName(String id) {
//some code
... = Long.valueOf(id);
....
....
callOtherMethod(Long.valueOf(id));
....
...
map.put("urId", Long.valueOf(id));
....
}
```

So is this okay while we consider performance and all that. else

this one is good to go

like :

```
void methodName(String id) {
//some code
Long longId = Long.valueOf(id);
... = longId;
....
....
callOtherMethod(longId);
....
...
map.put("urId", longId);
....
}
```

which one is best and why (if you can explain)?

Comment: second approach is best since you can avoid `valueOf(...)` function call

Comment: Is there a performance issue you need to fix? Otherwise, you should always prefer the most readable code, which is a question of taste and/or project rules. I prefer the second approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to use the second approach if the value you get back from `Long.valueOf()` (or any other method) should be used more than once. Because it's alsmot always cheaper to store it locally than to calculate it again.

For the example in question, it's not hard to calculate the performance difference with JMH. I created small benchmark that can calculate this:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class ValueOfPerfTest {

    @Param({ "1000" })
    private String number;

    @Param({ "10", "20", "30"})
    private long tokens;

    @Benchmark
    public void cachedValueOf(Blackhole blackhole) {
        Long l = Long.valueOf(number);

        // three times using the consume
        blackhole.consume(l);
        blackhole.consume(l);
        blackhole.consume(l);

        Blackhole.consumeCPU(tokens);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void nonCachedValueOf(Blackhole blackhole) {
        // three times using the consume
        blackhole.consume(Long.valueOf(number));
        blackhole.consume(Long.valueOf(number));
        blackhole.consume(Long.valueOf(number));

        Blackhole.consumeCPU(tokens);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Long valueOf(Blackhole blackhole) {
        Blackhole.consumeCPU(tokens);

        return Long.valueOf(number);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void baseline(){
        Blackhole.consumeCPU(tokens);
    }

}
```

I don't want to go for the specific of the JMH here, but main difference is that `nonCachedValueOf` is calling 3 times the `Long.valueOf()`, compared to only one time in the cached version. My expectations were that the non-cached version will be slower 3 times and that's basically what the results show:

```
 [java] Benchmark                                   (number)  (tokens)  Mode  Samples    Score   Error  Units
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.baseline                1000        10  avgt       10   11.238 ± 0.387  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.baseline                1000        20  avgt       10   30.392 ± 0.668  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.baseline                1000        30  avgt       10   50.217 ± 1.101  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.cachedValueOf           1000        10  avgt       10   37.368 ± 2.035  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.cachedValueOf           1000        20  avgt       10   54.614 ± 3.847  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.cachedValueOf           1000        30  avgt       10   74.412 ± 2.474  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.nonCachedValueOf        1000        10  avgt       10   82.329 ± 2.649  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.nonCachedValueOf        1000        20  avgt       10  100.595 ± 2.476  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.nonCachedValueOf        1000        30  avgt       10  118.715 ± 3.277  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.valueOf                 1000        10  avgt       10   35.815 ± 0.766  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.valueOf                 1000        20  avgt       10   53.074 ± 3.942  ns/op
 [java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.valueOf                 1000        30  avgt       10   73.378 ± 2.318  ns/op
```

If you dig a bit deeper into results you would come to the approximately following results if you exclude the baseline (here with 30 tokens):

```
[java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.cachedValueOf       24,195 ns/op
[java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.nonCachedValueOf    68,498 ns/op
[java] i.n.a.p.ValueOfPerfTest.valueOf             23,161 ns/op
```

Quite clear almost factor 3 slower.

Regarding your question for *every time using Long.valueOf creates any new object?*, the answer is yes if the number is not in the cache.. The java have the cache for the "frequently used values" which is by default there for numbers from -128 to 127. But it can be increased by using `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax` JVM option.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would be in favour of not repeating the same operation multiple times. So I would prefer your second approach.

When programming, the same piece of code written multiple times is often a bad smell, and if you can extract repeated pieces of code to be reusable, like extracting a repeated block to a parameterised method, or in this case assigning the output of `Long.valueOf(id)` to a variable, you can avoid verbose code that becomes hard to read.

Comment: Also note that this is not an issue of performance. It is very unlikely that you would see a measurable difference when choosing one over the other.

Comment: @Kayaman at every time using Long.valueOf creates any new object (like in string) for casting or not?. Can you explain in which way 2nd approach is beneficial